# Prove that $1+w^h+w^{2h}+\dots + w^{(n-1)h} = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Setting $w$ as:
>   $$w=\cos \frac{2\pi}{n} + i   \sin \frac{2\pi}{n}$$
>
> Prove that $$1+w^h+w^{2h}+\dots + w^{(n-1)h} = 0$$ 
>   whenever $h$ is not a multiple of $n$.

This is an exercise of my complex analysis class, so far I know that $A=\{1,w, w^2,\dots ,w^{n-1}\}$ are the *n*th roots of unity. So obviously for any $a \in A$ we have $a^n = 1$ (fact that I don't know how to use in the proof). Also we have that:

$$w^h=\cos \frac{2\pi(h)}{n} + i   \sin \frac{2\pi(h)}{n}$$

So $w^h$ would be the $\frac{n}{h}$th root of unity ? I'm honestly stuck with this problem, any hint would be a lot of help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the last term is $w^{(h-1)h}$ and not $w^{(n-1)h}$?

Comment: @Ben-ZT: Hmm, there seems to be a few problems with your question. First, are you sure that $w$ is not defined as $w = \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} + i \sin \frac{\2 pi}{n}$ (and then it indeed satisfies $w^n = 1$)? Second, are you sure that the sum doesn't have $n$ terms and not $h$? As stated, the claim is false as can be seen by taking $n = 2$ (and then $w = i$) and $h = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
1+w^h+w^{2h}+\dots + w^{(n-1)h}&=\sum^{n-1}_{j=0}(w^h)^j\\&=\frac{1-(w^h)^n}{1-w^h}\\
&=\frac{1-(w^n)^h}{1-w^h}\\
&=\frac{1-1^h}{1-w^h}=0
\end{align}

Comment: I don't understand why Ben-ZT hasn't ticked this guy by now. He's got the answer :)

Comment: Yup, sorry. He's been ticked

Answer (score 0):

We can multiply both sides by $w^h - 1$.

(1 + $w^h$ + $w^{2h}$ + ... + $w^{(h)n-1}$)($w^h$ - 1) = 0($w^h - 1$)

=> ($w^h$ - 1) + ($w^{2h}$ - $w^{h}$) + ... + ($w^{h(n-1)}$ - $w^{h(n-2)}$) + ($w^{h(n)}$ - $w^{h(n-1)}$).

Regrouping, we get:

-1 + $w^{h(n)}$ + ($w^h$ - $w^h$) + ($w^{2h}$ - $w^{2h}$) + ... + ($w^{h(n-1)}$ - $w^{h(n-1)}$)

Cancel, and you are left with:

-1 + $w^{h(n)}$

We know that $w^{h(n)}$ = 1.

Simply plug in, -1 + 1, and you get 0!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another proof for this old question which does not use the geometric series formula.

Think of the sequence of complex numbers $1,w^h,w^{2h},...,w^{(n-1)h}$ as $n$ equally spaced dots on the unit circle. Rotate them through an angle of $2\pi h/n$ (i.e. multiply them by $w^h$) and you get the exact same set of dots. So if their sum is $S$ then $w^hS=S$. But $w^h \ne 1$ so $S=0$.

You could, if you like, also write this proof out in algebraic form:
$$S = 1 + w^h + w^{2h} + ... + w^{(n-1)h}
$$
Multiply both sides by $w^h$ to get
\begin{align*}
w^hS &= w^h + w^{2h} + ... + \underbrace{w^{nh}}_{=\, (w^n)^h \, = \, 1^h \, = \, 1} \\
     &= 1 + w^h + w^{2h} + ... + w^{(n-1)h} \\
     &= S
\end{align*}
But, as said, $w^h \ne 1$, so $S=0$.

Comment: Isn’t that essentially the proof of the geometric series formula?

Comment: If you add one more step to my proof in algebraic form, then yes, you do indeed get the geometric series formula. The point of this proof, though, is that you can ignore the formula and do it with geometry.